# Prolog: display n-th element of list

Tags: recursion, prolog, predicate

Using Prolog:

Write a predicate dispnth to display the nth element of a list. You may assume that the input list always has n or more elements.

For Example:
`?- dispnth([1, [2, 3], 4, 5], 2, X).` should return `X = [2, 3]`

I have this so far:

```
dispnth([X|_], 0, X).
dispnth([_|Xs], N, X) :- 
   dispnth(N1, X, Xs),
   N is N1 + 1.
```

Comment: Please show what you have attempted so far and ask a specific question about that. Also `[2,3]` is the second element of the list, not the third.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought that my solution so far might just be confusing.

Comment: Actually it's not confusing at all, it is a good start. One thing that looks confused is your recursive call to `dispnth(N1, X, Xs)`. You have your arguments swapped around. It should be `dispnth(Xs, N1, X)`.

Answer (score 2):

First let's give the predicate a more descriptive name, say list_nth_element/3. Next you might like to consider an auxiliary predicate list_nth_element_/4 with an additional argument, that holds the current position. From your given example I assume that you start counting at 1, so that's going to be the start value for the fourth argument. Then the predicates might look something like this:

```
list_nth_element(L,N,E) :-
   list_nth_element_(L,N,E,1).

list_nth_element_([X|Xs],N,X,N).       % if the 2nd and 4th elements are equal X is the nth element
list_nth_element_([_X|Xs],N,E,P0) :-   % if the 2nd and 4th arguments
   dif(P0,N),                          % differ
   P1 is P0+1,                         % increment current position
   list_nth_element_(Xs,N,E,P1).       % and recurse
```

So essentially the fourth argument is used as a position indicator that is being incremented until you reached the desired position. However, there is no need to have this additional argument in the actual predicates interface, so it is "hidden" in the auxiliary predicate's interface.

Querying this predicate yields your desired result:

```
   ?- list_nth_element([1, [2, 3], 4, 5], 2, X).
X = [2,3] ? ;
no
```

You can also ask things like *Which element is at what position?*

```
   ?- list_nth_element([1, [2, 3], 4, 5], N, X).
N = X = 1 ? ;
N = 2,
X = [2,3] ? ;
N = 3,
X = 4 ? ;
N = 4,
X = 5 ? ;
no
```

Comment: This is exactly the built-in `nth1/3` by the way.

Comment: @DanielLyons: Almost. The first two arguments are flipped ;-)